# Performance of $geoWithin vs $near

Tags: mongodb, geolocation, database-performance

Just read this write up...

https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/geospatial-performance-improvements-in-mongodb-3-2

which posts these performance metrics..

[image]

Say you want to gather all user's within 100 meters, with each user stored as a Point...

Either you can create a 100mx100m Polygon, and use $geoWithin... OR use $near and set 100m as the maximum distance.

Am I right to conclude that the $geoWithin method will always be faster?

Comment: They do two different things. `$near` returns "nearest" as the naming suggests. And funny enough `$geoWithin` means "within the specified boundaries". In short, `$near` "sorts" the results to return, and that is always going to take more time than not sorting. So it depends on what you want. If "order" of "nearest" is important, then you use `$near`. If it is not, then use `$geoWithin` and a plain definition of a circle. Which is the only polygon the two share in common.

Comment: @NeilLunn right makes sense. I'm just talking about within the purview of using either to gather users within a given range.

Comment: You don't appear to be reading the whole comment. Completely different things with completely different usages. It's up to you to pick which one you actually need.